# how to get value using key path from nested dictionary dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know how to get the value of a nested dictionary or to update value of the nested dictionary using keypath in dart (Flutter).

Answer (score 1):

Simple recursive implementation:

```
  /// Get the value from the [map] using passed [path] of keys
  /// in the format key1.key2.key3... etc.
  /// Returns null if [path] do not exists.
  Object? getFromPath(Object? map, String path) {
    if (map is! Map<String, dynamic>) return null;
    int index = path.indexOf('.');
    if (index < 0) return map[path];
    return getFromPath(map[path.substring(0, index)], path.substring(index + 1));
  }
```

Example:

```
  final Map<String, Object> map = { 
    'a1': { 
      'b1': { 
        'c1': { 
          'd1': 'hello',
          'd2': 'world'
          }
        }
      }
    };
  
  print(getFromPath(map, 'a1.b1.c1.d1')); //hello
  print(getFromPath(map, 'a1.b1.c1.d2')); //world
```

Answer (score 1):

i think no need for recursion since this is a for loop

this should be better performance

```
dynamic getValueForKeyPath({@required Map<String, dynamic> json, @required String path}) {
final List<String> pathList = path.split('.');

Map<String, dynamic> _map = json;
for (String element in pathList) {
  if (_map[element] is Map<String, dynamic>) {
    _map = _map[element];
  } else {
    return _map[element];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dictionary like this:

```
{
    "example": {
        "a": "valA",
        "b": "valB",
        "c": "valC",
    }
}
```

You can create a class that parses this object:

```
class Example {
  String a;
  String b;
  String c;

  Example({
    this.a,
    this.b,
    this.c,
  });

  factory Example.parseJSON(Map<String, String> json) {
    return Example(
      a: json['example']['a'],
      b: json['example']['b'],
      c: json['example']['c'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: any other method to access like json['example.a']

Comment: That is not a syntax recognised by Dart. There are specific libraries that support this nested syntax, but that's a dependency on the project, and there are different use-cases for each.

Comment: can you tell me about those dependency
?

Comment: There is a detailed description about 2 topics and libraries that can use notation you mentioned: 
1. when doing app localization https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization
2. when doing json parsing https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
dynamic getValueForKeyPath(
  {required Map<String, dynamic> json, required String path}) {
final List<String> pathList = path.split('.');
final List<String> remainingPath = path.split('.');

for (String element in pathList) {
  remainingPath.remove(element);
  if (json[element] is Map<String, dynamic>) {
    return getValueForKeyPath(
        json: json[element], path: remainingPath.join('.'));
  } else {
    return json[element];
  }
}
```

And given your map look like:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = { "data": { "nestedData": { "nestedValue": { "value": "10" }, "targetValue": "20" }}};
```

You can get the nested 'value' by calling:

```
print('Result ${getValueForKeyPath(json: data, path: 'data.nestedData.nestedValue.value')}');
```

Which will print 'Result 10'